# Can we reuse spring MVC filters in Spring WebFlux apps

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am new to spring WebFlux and understand that the way we write filters in Spring WebFLux is different from the way it is written in Spring MVC (ServletFIlter , HandlerInterceptor) . We have some Spring MVC Filters already written , can we reuse it in Spring WebFlux , or do we have to rewrite it .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'll have to rewrite them. Spring-Webflux defines their own equivalents, with Reactive types. There's [`WebFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/WebFilter.html) class replacing functionality of `ServletFilter` and `HandlerInterceptor` classes.

The reason is simply that [WebFlux is not following the Servlet specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-new-framework), for better reactive support.